# Select data from range between conversational openings and closings (chat log analysis using SQL / H2 Database)

Tags: mysql, sql, h2, chatbot

I have a table named "conversations" and it holds data like this:

```
 TIMESTAMP       | ACTOR| CONTEXT| MESSAGE    | CLASSIFICATION
-----------------+------+--------+------------+-----------
01.02.2015 09:38 | user | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 09:46 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:19 | user | text   | hi bot!    | opening
01.02.2015 10:20 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:21 | user | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:22 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:23 | user | text   | ok bye bot | closing
01.02.2015 11:53 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 12:14 | user | text   | goodbye    | closing
01.02.2015 12:33 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 12:51 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
```

What I want to `SELECT` is the range between 'openings' and 'closings' in my dataset in order to separate successfully framed conversations from all other user inputs / bot outputs.

The expected output would be:

```
 TIMESTAMP       | ACTOR| CONTEXT| MESSAGE    | CLASSIFICATION
-----------------+------+--------+------------+-----------
01.02.2015 10:19 | user | text   | hi bot!    | opening
01.02.2015 10:20 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:21 | user | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:22 | bot  | text   | blablabla  | normal
01.02.2015 10:23 | user | text   | ok bye bot | closing
```

----------- Update

I executed the query proposed in the comments but H2 didn't output any data:

[Output_Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7kut.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Please include your expected output.

Comment: Of course. I just edited the initial post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I imagine you are a Date and you need to be between open and close parenthesis so:

```
(OPEN   date   CLOSE)
```

From this you have: `date >= OPEN  and date <= CLOSE`

But for this case:  `OPEN date1 CLOSE date2 CLOSE`

You need to check for date2 has an Open without close: `nearLeftOpen > nearLeftClose`

So final logic became:

**[SQL DEMO:](http://rextester.com/DKK42231)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.TIMESTAMP >= (SELECT MAX(IF (CLASSIFICATION='opening', TIMESTAMP, null))
                       FROM Table1 t2
                       WHERE t2.TIMESTAMP <= t1.TIMESTAMP)
  AND t1.TIMESTAMP <= (SELECT MIN(IF (CLASSIFICATION='closing', TIMESTAMP, null))
                       FROM Table1 t3
                       WHERE t3.TIMESTAMP >= t1.TIMESTAMP)      
  AND (SELECT MAX(IF (CLASSIFICATION='opening', TIMESTAMP, null))
       FROM Table1 t2
       WHERE t2.TIMESTAMP <= t1.TIMESTAMP) > 
      (SELECT MAX(IF (CLASSIFICATION='closing', TIMESTAMP, '1900-01-01'))
       FROM Table1 t3
       WHERE t3.TIMESTAMP < t1.TIMESTAMP)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

As you can see I change one normal to opening and also appear. Based in your data I don't know how would you like to handle those. Is up to you provide enough information for border cases so we know how to handle those.

This can be solve adding another condition inverting the last condition to make sure the closing doesn't have any other open before.

Still this code need further testing for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from
    (select
        t.*,
        case when @rangeStarted=1 then 1 else 0 end as inside_range,
        @rangeStarted:=case 
                         when CLASSIFICATION='opening' then 1
                         when CLASSIFICATION='normal' then @rangeStarted
                         when CLASSIFICATION='closing' then 0
                       end 
    from t, (select @rangeStarted:=0)
    order by TIMESTAMP) sub
where inside_range=1
```

We define a variable based on row (initially 0). The variable is set to 1 when we met 'opening' and reset back to 0 when we met 'closing'.

Then just leave  records where the variable is 1

UPDATED: to place in the subquery logic with ordering

UPDATED 2:

```
select
        t.*,
        case when @rangeStarted=1 OR CLASSIFICATION='opening' then 1 else 0 end as inside_range,
        @rangeStarted:=case 
                         when CLASSIFICATION='opening' then 1
                         when CLASSIFICATION='normal' then @rangeStarted
                         when CLASSIFICATION='closing' then 0
                       end  as r
from Table1 t, (select @rangeStarted:=0) as var
order by TIMESTAMP
```

Inner range corrected and tested in the test Juan Carlos Oropeza provided

Comment: what does the line `case when @rangeStarted=0 then 1 else 0 end,` ?? You dont seem to use it or assign an alias

Comment: Updated the logic. Incorrectly placed alias. The expression fills the field. If the row variable @rangeStarted is 1 we are inside range

Comment: Ok, now make sense ;)

Comment: I think you should use a subquery, because you need add `ORDER BY TIMESTAMP` otherwise you cant guarantee the order.

Comment: Updated to include order by logic

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment! However, eventhough the query seems to work, it doesn't output any  data (see screenshot 'Output_Info' in my updated initial post above). P.S.: I renamed CLASSIFICATION to DIALOG and 'opening', 'normal' and 'closing' to 'Beginning', 'Test' and 'Ending'. Do you have any idea why this happened? Best - henning.

Comment: @hmayer first start from the query without WHERE. Check whether the `@rangeStarted` chnages at all. Check exact spelling of the values.

Comment: @StanislavL just started the query without WHERE.  `@rangestarted` changes from 0 to 1 when there is a 'Beginning', but then it immediately switches back to 0 in the next row. Thus the variable is set back to 0 before we met 'Ending'.

Comment: @hmayer check why it happens. I cannot answer why blindly without real data. Could be problem of replacing 'normal' with 'Test'

Comment: @StanislavL I started the query without the first "select * from" and without the last "(select rangeStarted:=1)" parts. It seemed to work as far as rangestarted is set to 1 when we meet 'Beginning' and then stays 1 until we meet 'Ending'. One problem that remains is that rangestarted stays 1 even then when a 'Beginning' is followed by another 'Beginning' until the next 'Ending' is met. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @hmayer You must having something else wrong. Even when Stan query isnt perfect, does return values. Check here. http://rextester.com/SRHE77044

Comment: @StanislavL Check the demo the last `CLOSE` doesnt have 1. That is because MySql doesn't warrant user variables execution.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza corrected the query. It should be based on inside_range